# Error when generate Gradle Wrapper files

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native, gradle, gradlew

I have a react native project in ubuntu, and I want to generate Gradle Wrapper files so I install gradle and in `android/app` I have run this command

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 3.4.1
```

But when I run this command, I got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/MY_PROJECT/android/app/build.gradle' line: 122

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Could you please share the build.gradle file.

Comment: Thanks [@LazerBass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5118762/lazerbass) I solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem happened because I called `SigningConfig` without defined it

So I solved this problem by defining `SigningConfig` in `/var/MY_PROJECT/android/app/build.gradle`

```
...
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig { ... }
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
      }
    }
  }
  buildTypes { ... }
}
...
```

> if you want learn more about how to adding signing config to your app's gradle config click [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#adding-signing-config-to-your-app-s-gradle-config)